# Reloading html loop items using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a loop in my html table as the following :

```
<tr id="testId" repeat.for="item of items">
    <td>${item.attribute1}</td>
    <td>${item.attribute1}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to refresh the items list in the html when a javascript function is called with new items. How can I do this?

This is for node js. I am making an apirequest to get new items in javascript but i am not sure how to populate the html elements once the request returns a response. I had tried the following earlier in a for loop :

```
let itemsData = this.updateItemsData(accountId, currData);
if (itemsData !== null) {
   items.devices.push(itemsData); 
}
```

However, the html table is not updated with the new itemsData though the items list in javascript shows new data when printed.

I also tried doing document.getElementById("testId").innerHtml = newItems returned by ajax, but that gives me Object type instead of populating html with data

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: The most important tag is missing. I suppose this is angular?

Comment: Use ajax call to populate new values.

Comment: This is for node js. I am usign an ajax call to get new items in javascript but i am not sure how to populate the html elements once the ajax returns a response. I tried doing document.getElementById("testId").innerHtml = newItems returned by ajax, but that gives me Object type instead of populating html with data.

Comment: `items` is an array list, try to push new item in `items` array that should refresh your UI when new items are pushed in the `items` list. `items.push(newItem)` without seeing your nodejs code it'd be hard to tell

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I had tried the following earlier in a for loop : let itemsData = this.updateItemsData(accountId, res.data[i]);
   if (itemsData !== null) {items.devices.push(itemsData); } . However, the html table is not updated with the new itemsData though the items list in javascript shows new data when printed.

Comment: i have updated the question above so its more clear.